# Xcode 5 no console output C++ code

Tags: c++, xcode

Having problems with compiling my C++ code within Xcode 5 console window.

No errors with program and I have created the project file using command line tools within Xcode and selected C++ from the drop down menu.

The default "Hello World" program shows output however the code I have written below doesn't show anything.

All i get when running is "Build Succeeded".

Am i missing any required tools and can someone please explain how to set up the IDE correctly?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void read(std::istream& in, std::vector<std::string>& text)
{
   std::string line;
   while (std::getline(in, line))
      text.push_back(line);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    // Read the entire input into text. If the command line names a file,
    // read that file. Otherwise, read the standard input.

    std::vector<std::string> text; ///< Store the lines of text here

    if (argc < 2)
       read(std::cin, text);
    else
    {
       std::ifstream in (argv[1]);
       if (not in)
       {
           std::perror(argv[1]);
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       read(in, text);
    }

   // Part 2. Sorth the text.
   std::sort(text.begin(), text.end());

   // Part 3. Print the sorted text.
   std::copy(text.begin(), text.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without input parameters (which I'm guessing you didn't setup), you need to open the active console window to perform input. Shift-Cmd-C. The little window in the lower-right corner. Open it, click it once with the mouse cursor, then enter your data. Finish with Ctrl-D to send EOF.

Comment: thanks for the reply @WhozCraig I have the console window up and have tried inputting information into it however all it does it allow words to be typed in and nothing happens. I believe it is suppose to sort the text and then print them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have everything right to me. In order to get it to work what I did was type a few lines in the output box, THEN press enter, THEN press Ctrl+D, (the Ctrl+D command does not work unless you press it at the beginning of a new line) and then the program runs as expected.